# Matrix language and macro variables

Tags: spss

is there a way to use calculations made in matrix language (matrix-end matrix) as macro variables later in calculations?

Let say I calculate chi^2 and pvalue in matrix language and then I want to use them as my new macro variables for, let say, printing information about if the statistics is significant or not.

Of course I can use OMS to solve my problem but I want to find out if there is a possible way to get variables from matrix language to syntax later on.

Comment: Can you give an example (in pseudo-code) of what you want to do? Off the cuff I would say not in any easy way, as the MACRO facility is just a string parser (so you can't pass values to a variable, only names to a variable), although I may be misunderstanding what you are asking. [Raynald's SPSS page](http://spsstools.net/) is quite comprehensive, did you see if anything on there matches (or is similar) to your use case? There's always python as well if macro's won't cut it.

Comment: For example: 1. In matrix language: get data from dataset, compute chi2 and vcramer then assign values to macrovariable, end matrix language 2. Make table with custom tables 3. Use macro variable from matrix language to include in caption of table. But as I see, better will be use python...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Python programmability instead of macro.  It is much more powerful and flexible.  You can read about it in the books and articles section of the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral).  The site also provides the materials for getting started with programmability.

MATRIX can write datasets, which Python can read and manipulate - and it can even generate macro values from them.

HTH,
Jon Peck